# the meaning of peer authentication when set SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(0)？

Tags: linux, openssl

openssl：

```
void SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(SSL_CTX *ctx,int depth);

depth:
level 0:peer certificate
```

what is the meaning of peer authentication？

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at here: https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_verify.html

The depth parameter is about the limiting the length of a chain of certificates that one is willing to accept. Peer authentication, on the other hand, is a more generic concept that is about authenticating the parties involved in the communication, otherwise known as "peer". Relying on public key infrastructures and certificates is one way to achieve authentication but there could be other means too.

Back to OpenSSL (and SSL in general), the authentication is based on the so-called "chain of trust", which means that the software trust certain entities, often times big Certificate Authorities (CAs) whose certificates are typically distributed and installed alongside with the software, who in turn sign the certificates (vouch for) of some intermediate CAs, who in turn does the same for the "peer" (the last entity of the chain), which typically is the server that the software attempts to connect to. Since the software trust some root CAs, and the intermediate CAs present certificates signed by those trusted root CAs, these intermediate CAs are trusted as well, and because the intermediate CAs are trusted, the "peer" can be authenticated now as it presents certificate signed by the intermediate CAs.

Now due to different security concerns and resource limits, the length of a certificate chain ("depth") cannot go arbitrarily long. If I'm not wrong, the default limit of OpenSSL is 100. Other SSL implementations might choose a different number based on their targeted platforms and application scenarios.

`SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth()` is used to impose a user-desired limit on the chain verification procedure, so that any certificates presented in the chain above the limit would be ignored. The level 0, 1, 2 used in the documentation refers to the position of certificates in the chain, where level 0 is the peer (the end entity), level 1 is possibly a certificate of a CA that signed the level 0 certificate, level 2 is a certificate of another higher level CA that signed the level 1 CA certificate, so on and so forth.

Another related concept can be found as the pathLen option of the basic constraints extension of X.509 version 3 certificates. This is often times used by higher level CAs to limit the length of a chain that can be formed by certificates issued by lower level CAs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, but this seems wrong. The flags mentioned look like they're used for the `mode` parameter of `SSL_CTX_set_verify` and `SSL_set_verify`, not the `depth` parameter of `SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth`.